# How to add video renderer to local video track

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, webrtc

I am trying below code

I have taken view on which video should display

```
@IBOutlet var viewBG: UIView!

 var localVideoTrack : RTCVideoTrack!
```

I am trying to add UIView to local video track in this way

```
localVideoTrack.add(viewBG as! RTCVideoRenderer)
```

But getting below error

> Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1b4aa69c8) to
>   'RTCVideoRenderer'

Comment: localVideoTrack.add(viewBG as! RTCVideoRenderer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@IBOutlet var viewBG: RTCEAGLVideoView!

In storyboard also we need to set viewBG custom class as RTCEAGLVideoView